# Push Pop Enqueue/dequue

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

Which data structure supports both push and pop and enqueue/dequeue operations?
Both push and pop are stacks and enqueue/dequeue are of queue. Now how could a single data structure supports all 4.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: Exactly which data structure supports both??
Dequeue??

Comment: Yes, deque stands for double ended queue

Answer (score 0):

As the the documentation says, [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) can be used as a FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queue and it can be used as a LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stack as well. 
The queue methods which you are looking for are `addFirst(e)` which is the equivalent of `enqueue` and `addLast(e)` which is called `dequeue` in other languages.
It also has `push(e)` and `pop()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to implement the above functionality using a different data structure, a doubly linked list would be perfect. You can keep 2 pointers, one at the head and another at the tail. The LIFO and FIFO technique can be mimicked with this.